# RN Complaining useContext() hook when i dd not even use useContext()

Tags: react-native, expo, react-typescript

Sure we all have a good day. I have react native typescript application, as i created it from "npx create-expo-app" and it worked fine after the fresh installation and i could see the sample App.tsx file on my device but when I installed all my dependencies and created screens and component files, i ran it again, i resolved all syntax errors and I used "npx expo start" expecting the app to launch on my device but i got error. The installed dependencies are

```
npm install @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@6.5.2 @react-navigation/native-stack@6.9.13 @expo/vector-icons axios@1.4.0 formik@2.4.3 yup@1.2.0 jsonwebtoken@9.0.1 
jwt-decode@3.1.2 moment react-native-status-bar-height@2.6.0 
@react-native-async-storage/async-storage react-native-paper 
react-native-safe-area-context react-native-screens
```

*****THE PROBLEM - ERROR******

```
  ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'useContext' of null, js engine: hermes
 
  ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

*****EXPECTATION******

I expected the application to display because there was no syntax errors and I did not even use useContext() hook in all my screens and component files, i do not know where it saw useContext() and why it is complaining useContext().

Thank you in advance for your kind support.